# Trying to understand Golang pluralization

Tags: go, pluralize, cldr

I'm trying to understand pluralization in Go. The example from the docs https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message/catalog#hdr-String_interpolation does not work. The method `plural.Select` does not event exist. It should be `plural.Selectf`. Note the `f` at the end.

```
message.Set(language.English, "You are %d minute(s) late.",
catalog.Var("minutes", plural.Selectf(1, "one", "minute")),
catalog.String("You are %d ${minutes} late."))
p := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
p.Printf("You are %d minute(s) late.", 5)
```

I found another tutorial here https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/internationalization-i18n-go/. This code works fine

```
message.Set(language.English, "You have %d problem",
    catalog.Var("minutes", plural.Selectf(1, "%d", "one", "minute", "other", "minutes")),
    catalog.String("You are %d ${minutes} late."))
printer := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
printer.Printf("You have %d problem", 1)
printer.Println()
printer.Printf("You have %d problem", 3)
printer.Println()

// result
// You are 1 minute late.
// You are 3 minutes late.
```

Both examples use the advanced string interpolation. Now I'm trying to understand `plural.Selectf`. What is the first argument `1` doing? Why do I need the second argument `%d`? I think I understand the rest

```
"one"  : "minute"
"other": "minutes"
```

I also saw `%[1]d` in `catalog.String`. What does this do?

Thanks a lot! I'm super confused right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go!

The first argument of `plural.Selectf` is an `int`. So it can be any valid integer.
The second argument is a `string`. It should be a format verb i.e `%d` or `%s` or `%f`
The third argument is an empty interface, could receive any type i.e string, struct, catalog.Message, ..

Let's take this example,

```
func main() {

    var (
            msg = plural.Selectf(2, "%d",
                "=10", "%[1]d task and %[2]d processes remaining!", // interface 1
                "=1", "%[1]d task and %[2]d processes", // interface 2
                "other", "%d tasks and %d processes!" // interface 3
            )
            key = "%d task - %d process"
            tag = "en"
        )

        lTag := language.MustParse(tag)
        message.Set(lTag, key, msg)

        p := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
        p.Printf("%d task - %d process", 1, 10)

}
```

Here we have created a `NewPrinter` with language English and set the translation messages with the key `%d task(s) remaining!` for tag `en`(short code for English language).

When `p.Printf("%d task - %d process", 1, 3)` line executes, the translation mechanism takes the first argument(format specifier) i.e `%d task - %d process` and checks for the message by comparing with key we set in for `en` tag. If the key is found, then it processes the message i.e `msg`.

Here the `Selectf`s first argument says that take `nth` (i.e 2nd in our case) format verb's value from `Printf` (i.e 10 in the second value for %d) and compare with selector of cases i.e `=10` in the case 1 (interface 1). If the comparison is success then returns the processed value i.e `1 task and 10 processes` in case 1.

If the `Printf` receives values for 2nd %d other than 1 & 10 then it would return the value from case 3 (interface 3)

And,

The `%[n]d` could be used like,

`fmt.Printf("%[2]d %[1]d\n", 11, 22)` and it prints `22 11`.

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: It starts making sense. I still do not understand the second argument to `plural.Selectf` `"%d"`. I've tried changing it and it seems like I can write anything I want there. I literally wrote "anything" and it still works.

Comment: What i am aware of the second argument to `plural.Selectf` is that it accepts only `%d, %f, %g, %e`. If we provide other than these, it is simply ignoring the value. And this format verb is been used with catalog.Message type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer by Thaadikkaaran, regarding the purpose of the second parameter to `plural.Selectf`:

As stated in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7/feature/plural#Selectf), "This is especially relevant for non-integer values".

The format string is applied to the argument before comparing it to the different "case" conditions, essentially allowing you to *trim floating point values to the precision desired for the comparison*.

```
message.Set(language.English, "%f%% battery", plural.Selectf(1, "%f",
    "<50", "Your battery is less than half full.",
    "other", "You still have enough battery left.",
))
p := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
p.Printf("%f%% battery", 49.99999)

fmt.Println()

message.Set(language.English, "%f%% battery", plural.Selectf(1, "%.4f",
    "<50", "Your battery is less than half full.",
    "other", "You still have enough battery left.",
))
p.Printf("%f%% battery", 49.99999)
```

prints

> Your battery is less than half full.
>
> You still have enough battery left.